# multi variable differential equation problem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Can anyone shows me how to solve this differentiation question?

I've tried a lot of method, but still can't get the right answer.

$ \int\int x^2 dx dy\: (where \: x^2+y^2 \leq1) $

A suggestion is using cylinder coordinates transformation.

Here is the form I come up with:
$x=rcos\alpha,y=rsin\alpha$

$\int r^2 dr(0\leq r\leq 1) *\int cos^2(\alpha)dx(0\leq \alpha\leq 2\pi) $

The answer is $\pi/4$, but I can only get $\pi/3$

Can anyone tell me where goes wrong?

Comment: What differential equation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your mistake lies with the rewriting of the integral.

To rewrite any integral using another coordinate system, you need to include a scaling factor (known as the determinant of the Jacobian; to put it crudely, it describes the magnitude of distortion of space when switching coordinate systems). In the case of polar coordinates, (a.k.a., cylindrical coordinates, which is a term better suited to describing a coordinate system 3-space rather than 2-space).

Thus when rewriting $$\iint_C x^2dxdy$$ (where $C=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}:x^2+y^2\leq 1\}$) using polar coordinates, although $$\iint_C r^2\cos^2\theta drd\theta$$ does contain an accurate substitution for the integrand, you haven't appropriately changed the differential elements, which means that what you're really doing is solving $$\iint_C x^2 drd\theta$$ whereas you want to be solving $$\iint_C x^2 r drd\theta=\iint_C r^3\cos^2\theta drd\theta=\int_0^1r^3dr\int_0^{2\pi}\cos^2\theta d\theta=\frac{1}{4}\cdot\pi=\frac{\pi}{4}$$.

Comment: oh,thanks! I totally forgot that.